# Rolling12Month Data in sql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get rolling 12 months and rolling 4 months data from a table.

```
Select Month
,Organization
,Trade
,Sum(sum(NS)) over (partition by [Organization], Trade order by Month),
from Table_Name
group by
Month,
Organization,
Trade
```

however i am facing challenge where there is no sales for a particular trade in a month.

[image]

the month in which there is no sale is not adding the previous month as well for R4month number. For eg in above example if feb doesn't have any sales for a particular trade then the monthly rolling 4 month of Feb is not even adding previous month and is showing blank as result.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't fill gaps, if you have no `month 2` in the data, there will be no `month 2` in the results.

Either fill in the blanks in the reporting layer (seemingly excel in your case), or fill in the blanks in the data.

One way to do the latter is to create a template for the results you want, and then join your data on to that.  For example, if you have a calendar table to join on, you can make sure all the months you want to report on exist in at least one table used in your query.

If you also have a table of organisations and trades, then you can join those "dimension" tables together to make your template, then `LEFT JOIN` your data to it.

This also helps you get the `12 month` and `4 month` rolling windows.  Because, now you know you always have all the months, you can use `ROWS BETWEEN` in your window functions *(where each source row corresponds to one month, because it's done after the initial aggregation)*.

```
SELECT
   organization.id
  ,trade.id
  ,calendar.month_id
  ,SUM(SUM(data.ns)) OVER (
     PARTITION BY organization.id, trade.id
         ORDER BY calendar.month_id
     ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING
              AND CURRENT ROW   -- 11 + current = 12
   )
FROM
  organisation
CROSS JOIN
  trade
CROSS JOIN
  calendar
LEFT JOIN
  data
    ON  data.organisation_id = organisation.id
    AND data.trade_id        = trade.id
    AND data.month           = calendar.month_id
GROUP BY
    organisation.id,
    trade.id,
    calendar.month_id
```